# CSS - Select each last item in a row and apply margin

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following design:

[image]

and each time I hover an attachment, I have the ability to delete it:

[image]

Sometimes, when having many attachments and I hover an attachment the row is too long and the last attachment in the row jumps to the next row.

I tried to google it and found the usage of (nth-last(4n)) but I don't know how many items i have in each row.

I thought about something like this:

```
last-child-in-a-row { margin-right: 10px; }
```

So, in that case i will have enough space for the growing `x` element.

Is there any suggested workaround/best-practice for this?

EDIT:

HTML (rendered from React):

```html
<div class="attachmentHolder">
  <button class="attachmentButton">
    <svg class="leftAttachment" ... />
    <a ...> some text </a>
    <svg class="attachmentClose" ... />
  </button>
  <button class="attachmentButton">
    <svg class="leftAttachment" ... />
    <a ...> some text 2 </a>
    <svg class="attachmentClose" ... />
  </button>
  ...
  ...
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.attachmentHolder {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.attachmentButton {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 6px;
  margin: 0 8px 10px 0;

  .attachmentClose {
    max-width: 0;
    transition: max-width .1s ease-out, margin-left .1s ease-out;
  }

  &:hover {
    .attachmentClose {
      max-width: 25px;
      margin-left: 8px;
      margin-right: 8px;
      fill: $secondary;
    }
  }
}


.leftAttachment {
  height: 20px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 4px 3px 0;
}
```

Comment: show your code please

Comment: think differently .. why trying to adjust the last element in the row .. adjust the hovered element and be sure it won't grow when you will add the icon

Comment: There is no such selector. It might make more sense to absolutely position that `x`, than to have single elements grow in size - that way, they all will stay in place, whereas right now it sounds with your current solution, when I hover over the first item in a row, all the rest of them in the same row will move to the right …? That is an ugly effect to begin with IMHO, even without the problem of the last item possibly breaking to a new row.

Comment: @omri_saadon, the case is to stop jumping last item on hover, isnt it? And all items are placed in div with flex? Can you add html and css for picture above?

Comment: Added an example code of my usage, it's a bit complex as it comes from few different react components.

Comment: Indeed... **there is no such CSS selector** - You need Javascript.